# Exporting org-mode file to LaTeX with different document font

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

The default for exporting to LaTeX from org-mode files is to have the article document class at size 11pt font `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`.

How do I get the exported LaTeX file to be a specified font size, namely 12pt?

Comment: Simply: \documentclass[12pt]{article}

Comment: Tried that it did not work. Upon export it still inserts `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` at the top and then `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` further down which doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problably the simplest is to add `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [12pt]` in you file, as discussed in the [doc](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-header-and-sectioning.html#LaTeX-header-and-sectioning).

> The LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS keyword or EXPORT_LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS property can specify the options for the \documentclass macro. These options have to be provided, as expected by LaTeX, within square brackets.
>
> You can also use the LATEX_HEADER and LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA2 keywords in order to add lines to the header. See the docstring of org-latex-classes for more information.
>
> An example is shown below.
>
> ```
> #+LATEX_CLASS: article
> #+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
> #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xyz}
>
> * Headline 1
>   some text
> ```